# Solving algebraic inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I been struggling trying to solve this inequality by hand

$$x+\sqrt{x+3} < 0$$

how should I proceed?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos:put $x=-3$ to see $$-3+\sqrt{-3+3} <o \\\checkmark$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos : the answer is $$x \in [-3,\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2})$$

Comment: The answers i previously got to a similar question my help:
[My previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286388/assuming-a-positive-in-an-inequality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\sqrt{x+3}<-x$$
We can see that $x$ must be negative, since the square root is nonnegative. Therefore, assume $x<0$. We also need $x\geq-3$ for the square root to be defined. Under these assumptions, that first inequality is equivalent to
$$x+3 < x^2$$
$$\iff x^2-x-3>0$$
$$\iff x > \frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2} \,\,\,\,\mathrm{or}\,\,\,\, x < \frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}$$
Therefore, 
$$x\in [-3, 0) \cap \left(-\infty, \frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right) = \left[ -3,  \frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)$$

Comment: why was the inequality sign preserved undersquaring?

Comment: @Buraian Before squaring it's assumed that $-3\leqslant x<0$ and accepted as ongoing constraint, cf the last line.

Answer (score 1):

$$x+\sqrt { x+3 } <0\Rightarrow \begin{cases} x+3\ge 0 \\ x+3<{ x }^{ 2 } \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} x\ge -3 \\ { x }^{ 2 }-x-3>0 \end{cases}\Rightarrow \cap \begin{cases} x\ge -3 \\ x\in \left( -\infty ;\frac { 1-\sqrt { 13 }  }{ 2 }  \right) \cup \left( \frac { 1+\sqrt { 13 }  }{ 2 } ;+\infty  \right)  \end{cases}\Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow -3\le x<\frac { 1-\sqrt { 13 }  }{ 2 } $$

Answer (score 0):

the inequality is equivalent to
$$\sqrt{x+3}<-x$$ with $$x\geq-3$$ and $$-x>0$$ thus we have
$$-3\le x<0$$
after squaring we get
 $$0<x^2-x-3$$
can you finish?

Comment: @

Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: you made a typo ,$x+8$ in the second line

Comment: You have an 8 instead of a 3 in the first equation

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x+3}$.

Thus, $f$ is an increasing function.

Also, $$f\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)=\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}+3}=$$
$$=\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{14-2\sqrt{13}}{4}}=\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{13}-1}{2}=0.$$

But the domain gives $x\geq-3$, which gives the answer $\left[-3,\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)$